# Coupled Nonlinear Differential Equations Problem

Tags: differential-equations

I have a big problem solving a set of coupled nonlinear differential equations using `NDSolve`.

Solving the equations by themselves works quite well but if I want to couple them I get

> "NDSolve::conarg: The arguments should be ordered consistently. >>"

but I can not see my mistake.

Maybe you guys can help me with this.

The first equation is:

```
D[Int[z, t], z] == -(c Int[z, t]^k), Int[0, t] == a (Exp[-4 Log[2] (t/f)^2])
```

This is easy to solve using Parametric `NDsolve`.

The second equation is (not coupled):

```
D[nn[t], t] == b Int2[t]^k, nn[t <= tmin1] == 0
```

with

```
Int2[t]= a (Exp[-4 Log[2] (t/f)^2])
```

This is also solved using `ParametricNDSolve` with `Method -> {StiffnessSwitching, Method -> {ExplicitRungeKutta, Automatic}}`

The coupling is simply givien by the fact that `Int2[t]` should now be `Int[z,t]` thus my code should be:

```
ParametricNDSolve[
  {
   D[Int[z, t], z] == -(c Int[z, t]^k)
   , Int[0, t] == a (Exp[-4 Log[2] (t/f)^2])
   , D[nn[z, t], t] == σ Int[z, t]^k 
   , nn[z, t /; t <= tmin1] == 0
   }
  , {Int, nn}
  , {z, 0, 100 10^-9}
  , {t, tmin1, tmax1}
  , {a}
  , MaxSteps -> 100000
  , MaxStepSize -> Automatic
  , StartingStepSize -> Automatic
  , Method -> {StiffnessSwitching, 
    Method -> {ExplicitRungeKutta, Automatic}}
  , AccuracyGoal -> 2
  , PrecisionGoal -> 2
  , EvaluationMonitor -> Automatic
  ];
```

`b`,`c`,`f`,`k` are just constants, a is a parameter of interest.

I would be glad if you could help me with this (maybe not so big) problem.

Thank you so much in advance.

Best greetings

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
nn[z, t /; t <= tmin1] == 0
```

you should state the boundary condition as

```
nn[z, tmin1] == 0
```